# Safe way to synchronize ressources between servers through php / linux

Tags: php, linux, synchronization, rsync

I need to synchronize ressources from a master server to a slave server. I use rsync because it can synchronize folder recursively using incremental file list. I have been able to make it work the simpliest way using ssh-keys. Everything is fine but it doesn't work through php *shell_exec* function. Here is what I have done so far, and where I am getting stuck. Help would be appreciated!

Master and slave servers are on ubuntu 14.04.4

## Creation of the ssh-key folder within user's home directory.

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
```

## Creation of a private / public ssh key with no passphrase

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -q -P ""
```

## Unsure slave server can receive master public ssh key

```
// log in slave server
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

## Copy public key to the slave server (where I want to synchronize ressources)

```
// log in master server
su ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [slave user]@[slave host]
```

## Test synchronisation of an existing folder... let's say www/js/

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress ~/www/js/ [slave user]@[slave host]:~/www/js/
```

Yay, all works fine.

I log on slave server, remove www/js folder recursively.

I log on master server

I create a simple php script to test if it work within as a "shell command"

test.php

```
var_dump(shell_exec('rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress ~/www/js/ [slave user]@[slave host]:~/www/js/'));
```

The synchronization doesn't work from php. Probably because php runs width www-data user? How can I make it work safely from pĥp?

Comment: You could use rsync or you could store the home directories on a common folder and mount them on each server.

Comment: your home variable `~` might not be expanding properly. try the full path

Comment: Slave server in my case are like content delivery. Mount a common folder would be okay, but in my case php creates or update ressources, then must synchronize them on slave servers, and php must keep running. Therefore, synchronization must be fired from php.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Absolute path, no success :/

Comment: I tryed to make ssh-key visible for www-data (chown 0710) but rsync now fails and says private ssh key may not be visible for other users.

Answer (score 0):

** edit : this answer is not a secure. Please see my other answer **

---

I finally found out how to make it work

copy private ssh-key to www-data's home folder. Then php will be able to rsync through shell_exec function

www-data's home folder is /var/www/ (in my case Ubuntu 14)

## create .ssh folder if not present

```
mkdir /var/www/.ssh
chown www-data /var/www/.ssh
chmod 0700 /var/www/.ssh
```

## copy ssh key and set proper rights

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa /var/www/.ssh
chown www-data /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 0600 /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This line now works for me :

```
shell_exec('rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress [absolute_path]/www/js/ [slave user]@[slave host]:~/www/js/');
```

If it helps someone...

But since I know a lot in security but can't say I'm a specialist, I wonder if that is secure ?

Comment: No. It's not secure. You should be minimising the content the webserver uid can write to. Although this is not a vulnerability in itself, it provides a means for someone to take over both your servers if they can find a chink elsewhere. The simplest solution (assuming you have root access) is to setup the SSH access for another user and invoke it via sudo (if required) from PHP. But that also means you need a permissions model if you don't already have one.

Comment: In my case, the backend is actually all sercure, runs for a long time, and has been well tested. Proper authentification and authorization are performed before php creates / updates / rsync ressources. But like you said, if php invoke it via an other user, the chick could be found anyway....

Comment: This is a very naive view of computer security.

Comment: @symcbean would be nice to elaborate. It is nice to have a point of view but Stackoverflow shares problems and solutions.

Comment: getting something to work within the constraints of the problem you have defined is not the same thing as making it secure against all possible attacks.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the elaboration. So if www-data has the right to connect via ssh to a slave server is not secure. If I create user, lets say, "slavesync", with proper ssh-key installed, and I perform rsync with that user from php, that would be more secure? How would I be able to execute rsync with "slavesync" user via php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110396/discussion-between-symcbean-and-simmoniz).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by symcbean, my previous answer was is a security risk. **Making www-data able to access remote hosts without password may be really dangerous**. A better approach is to set up a linux user, lets say "wwwsync", that will handle rsync with remote hosts, and let www-data execute rsync "under wwwsync user". That way, we can control / secure rsync by setting up what wwwsync user can and cannot do.

**Creation of a linux user that will handle synchronization (let's say wwwsync), and create the ssh-key folder within user's home directory.**

```
// log as root user    
adduser wwwsync
// log as wwwsync
su wwwsync
// create ssh folder for ssh key creation
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
```

**Creation of a private / public ssh key with no passphrase**

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -q -P ""
```

**Unsure slave server can receive master public ssh key**

```
// log in slave server
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Copy public key to the slave server (where I want to synchronize ressources)**

```
// log in master server as wwwsync
su ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub [slave user]@[slave host]
```

**Make www-data user (php) able to perform rsync under wwwsync user**

```
// log in as root
su root
// edit sudo configuration
sudo visudo
// add this line at the bottom of the file
www-data ALL=(wwwsync) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync
```

This line will then work properly from php

```
shell_exec('rsync -H -u wwwsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress ~/www/js/ [slave user]@[slave host]:~/www/js/')
```

**Next important step** : Make sure that wwwsync has rights and permissions properly set, according to your needs, so www-data won't synchronize unwanted ressources to your remote servers.