# Allow www-data to execute rsync under other user (php)

Tags: php, linux, rsync, sudo, sudoers

I would like to allow php to perform rsync under an other users's privileges, let's say wwwsync user.

How can I acheive this with sudo configuration? Here is what I have done :

In sudo configutaion (sudo visudo)

```
www-data www-data-sync=(wwwsync) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync
```

This line works as excpected when logged as wwwsync user

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress ~/some/path/ [remoteuser]@[remotehost]:~/some/path/
```

But this line executed from php using *shell_exec()* does not work

```
sudo -u wwwsync rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress ~/some/path/ [remoteuser]@[remotehost]:~/some/path/
```

Is it the right way to execute rsync under wwwsync user? Is the sudo configuration set properly?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out how to make it work.

sudoer configuration was wrong. Alias must be ALL, not a random alias.Also, 
"rsync" must have "-H" option set so the command sets the target home folder as home folder while command is executed.

In sudo configuration (sudo visudo)

```
www-data ALL=(wwwsync) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync
```

This line executed from php using shell_exec() does work (with ssh key properly set for user wwwsync and remote host)

```
sudo -H -u wwwsync rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress /some/path/ [remoteuser]@[remotehost]:~/some/path/
```

**Note :** wwwsync rigths / perms must be carfully set so www-data won't synchronize unwanted folders to remote host.

This finally allows me to perform safe ressource synchronisation between a master server and slave servers : [Safe way to synchronize ressources between servers through php / linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870627/safe-way-to-synchronize-ressources-between-servers-through-php-linux/36875969)

If that could help...